# Access to the joints cartesian position from KDL chain

Tags: ros, kdl, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
for my project I have to know the cartesian joint position, and possibly also the orietation. I have my chain created using KDL and DH parameter. There is a possibility to access to that information from the chain? I mean, some function like: `chain.getJointPose()...`

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239318/access-to-the-joints-cartesian-position-from-kdl-chain/) by [almosca](https://answers.ros.org/users/22088/almosca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2016-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See http://orocos.org/kdl/UserManual/kinematic_solvers for more information.

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Smits](https://answers.ros.org/users/350/ruben-smits/) with karma: 543 on 2016-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [almosca](https://answers.ros.org/users/22088/almosca/) on 2016-07-12**:
Hi thanks for the answer. I think that that will not work for me. I found the solution !!!